# Install country specific app from other country app store

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I have my App Store set on country XYZ and I am currently long term traveling (for a few months) in country ABC.

Hence I'd like to install some apps relevant to country ABC. I was able to do that for some apps. But some others tell me that I cannot install them because I am on another country App Store (country XYZ).

Doing a little bit of googling lead me to [such thread explaining what could be some reasons behind this annoying situations](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5395090?start=0&tstart=0).

Is there a way for me to still install these country specific apps **without switching my App Store country settings**?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no.

Apps can be limited by developers and/or by Apple to specific countries. This may be because of copyright, licensing, targeted markets, missing translation among other reasons.

As of this limitation you need to change your App Store country settings / your country specific Apple ID.

Comment: Whatever the reason... it is super annoying. So many apps I do not have access to!